# get the option chosen from a form in html and assign it to php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to collect the option chosen from a form in html and use it to increment a value in a mysql database.
The idea is:
chose your name (from the html form, already populated by mysql)
chose name of your opponent (from the html form, already populated by mysql)
click submit to: increment one victory to you and increment one defeat to your opponent.

I have the following code:

```
echo '<select name="tabela">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['Nome'] . "'>" . $row['Nome'] . "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';

echo $teste=$_POST['tabela'];

if ($teste=='Filipe')
{
$sql="UPDATE Jogadores SET Vitorias=Vitorias+1 WHERE Nome='Filipe'";
mysql_select_db('aventino');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
}
```

It populates the html form but I can't get 1) the name that is there by default 2) the name that the user chooses.
I have been trying lots of solutions and nothing seems to exist in order to know and extract which option is chosen, before clicking submit button!

Many thanks
F

Comment: You need to use javascript to know what option is selected _before_ clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<select name="tabela">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Nome'] . "'>" . $row['Nome'] . "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';


/**
 * get data and update
 */
if (isset($_POST['tabela']))
{
    $sql="UPDATE Jogadores SET Vitorias=Vitorias+1 WHERE Nome='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tabela'])."'";
    mysql_select_db('aventino');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't resolve my problem. Whenever I press submit (in the lower button on the page), the database does not get updated. I put an echo to test if the function was being true, but it doesn't echo anything. I think if (isset($_POST['tabela'])) is ignored somewhow.